# How to get teh real value inside a flux flow, instead of FluxLift?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactor

I'm getting an `Publisher<DataBuffer> inputStream` as argument. I want to convert that stream into a String, log that string, and then I have to pass that string as again as a `Publisher` to another method.

Example:

```
public Flux<Object> decode(Publisher<DataBuffer> inputStream) {
    return DataBufferUtils.join(inputStream)
                .map(buffer -> StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer.asByteBuffer()).toString())
                .doOnNext(arg -> LOGGER.info(arg))
                .map(arg -> library.delegate(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> arg))) 
                .flatMapIterable(arg -> {
                     System.out.println(arg); //instanceof FluxLift??
                     return List.of(arg);
                );
}

class ExternalLibrary {
    //this ALWAYS returns a FluxLift
    public Flux<Object> delegate(Publisher<String> inputString) {
        //does not matter, I don't have control of this.
        //lets assume it does the following:

        return Flux.just(input).
            flatMapIterable(buffer -> List.of("some", "result"))
            .map(arg -> arg);
    }
}
```

Question: why is the argument in the final `flatMapInterable()` always of type `FluxLift`? And moreover: how can return the real value here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is the argument in the final flatMapInterable() always of type FluxLift?

Because your map function returns Flux

```
.map(arg -> library.delegate(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> arg)))
```

> how can return the real value here?

When mapping fuction returns reactive type, use one of `flatMap*` fuction instead of `map`. `flatMapMany` fits in your case:

```
public Flux<Object> decode(Publisher<DataBuffer> inputStream) {
    return DataBufferUtils.join(inputStream) //Mono<DataBuffer>
                .map(buffer -> StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer.asByteBuffer()).toString()) //Mono<String>
                .doOnNext(arg -> LOGGER.info(arg)) //Mono<String>
                .flatMapMany(arg -> library.delegate(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> arg))) // Flux<Object>
                .flatMapIterable(arg -> {
                     System.out.println(arg); // instanceof Object
                     return List.of(arg);
                );
```

Comment: So I'd have wrap it inside an extra mono? like `.flatMap(arg -> Mono.just(libraray.delegate(...)));`?

Comment: But my main problem is: the external library always returns a `FluxLift` when calling `delegate()`. How can I then convert this, so that on calling `block()` elsewhere I receive the real value?

Comment: you should never call block in a reactive application. It defeats the purpose of having a reactive application.

Comment: If I need the value somewhere, I could call block(). But it also could be any other operation. The main problem is the library already returning a `FluxLift` what I cannot change...